# Jlabel, JFrame, SqlQuery

Tags: java

For this program you are to create the program described below. Once completed you are to submit an executable JAR file as well as your .java source file to complete this question.

This program will lookup information in the course MySQL database, present that information, and calculate a result based on that data. Presenting utilizing a Java Swing JFrame and JLabel UI elements.

You are to lookup in the MySQL database INFS3070, from the SALES and EXPENSES tables.  This lookup MUST be performed when the application is launched and not simply be a static value that is hard coded into the JLabel in the JFrame window.

From the SALES table you should display the SUM of all Weekly_Sales from Store # 1 and display the results in a JLabel that displays: Sales: $  xxxxxxxx.

From the EXPENSES table you should display the SUM of all values in the Amount column for Store # 1 and display the results in a JLabel that displays: Expenses: $ xxxxxxxx

In the third JLabel field you are to subtract the returned value of EXPENSES from the returned value of SALES and display the results in a JLabel field that displays: "Profit: $ xxxxxxxx

Program specifics:

UI ELEMENTS:

JFrame:
Bounds: (100, 100, 400, 300)
JLabel
Font: 12pt Tahoma
All UI alignment should be very similar to the screen design shown below.

Database Information:

DB Location: 128.198.162.204
Username: infsclass
Password: webclass

```
import java.awt.color.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;

public class INFS3070Final {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel label;
        JLabel label2;
        JLabel label3;
        
        label = new JLabel("Sales: $ ");
        label.setBounds(50,20,100,30);
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        
        label2 = new JLabel("Expenses: $ ");
        label2.setBounds(50,80,100,30);
        label2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        
        label3 = new JLabel("Profit: $ ");
        label3.setBounds(50,150,100,30);
        label3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(label2);
        frame.add(label3);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        
        frame.setBounds(100,100,400,300);
        
        try {
        String url = "jdbc.mysql;//localhost/INFS3070";
        String user = "infsclass";
        String password = "webclass";
        
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement sqlQuery = null;
        ResultSet results = null; 
        
        
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        
        sqlQuery = connection.createStatement();
        
        results = sqlQuery.executeQuery("Select * FROM Store #1");
        
        results.getString("Sales");
        results.getString("Expense");
        results.getString("Profit");
        
        
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: (1-) We are not interested in your assignment. If you have a specific problem then state what the problem is.

Comment: Im having a difficult time getting the information from the sql querry and then getting them to appear on the jframe

Comment: 1) Update your question with the problem. 2) Do you have a System.out.println(...) to display the data in your ResultSet? 3) Once you know you have data, then you worry about displaying it on the frame. You need to solve one problem at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You want to update the labels with the values from results.

For example,

```
label1.setText(results.getString("Sales: $ " + results.getString("Sales"));
```